# How to enforce "accept" OR " format" parameters in HTTP URL to enforce XML response from server than a JSON

Tags: json, xml, api, rest, http

I am always getting JSON response for my HTTP request to access one ORDS-Oracle Rest Data Services API:
**http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/employees/**
[image]

However my requirement is to get XML response. I tried to choose XML from drop down list available at POSTMAN, however content is not changing to XML.

I need a way to specify parameter as part of HTTP URL so that response is XML than JSON and I tried to change URL like below:
Way1:
**http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/employees?format=xml**
Way2:
**http://abcdef.us.oracle.com:8001/claims-ws/api/generic/lineofbusinesses/421?Content-Type:application/xml**
Way3:
**http://abcdfef.us.oracle.com:8001/claims-ws/api/generic/lineofbusinesses/421?Accept:application/xml**
Way4:
**http://abcdef.us.oracle.com:8001/claims-ws/api/generic/lineofbusinesses/421?Accept=application/xml**

However nothing is working and response is always JSON.
Any suggestion?

Comment: There's really no single standard way to tell a web service to return a XML  Worse, there are several common ways, all think they are "standard".  Looks like you've already tried all the usual ways, time to contact whoever created the web service to get support. Good  luck.

Comment: Thanks William, I only created REST API resources for by oracle database tables using ORDS tool.This is automated way to expose a data base object as REST API resource and I do not have any control there on  how does that tool create it.

Comment: I see.  Seems like a pretty standard thing from a quick Google search, but I'm a SQL Server guy, not Oracle.  See https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-create-basic-rest-web-services-using-plsql#stored-procedure-xml